# Are these expressions (Gamma function and binomial) identical for $n\in \mathbb Z$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, factorial, gamma-function

For $n\in \mathbb Z$ and $n\ge 0$, prove that:

$$\frac{2\sqrt{\pi}\,\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}+n)}{\Gamma(n+1)}=\frac{\pi}{2^{2n-1}}\binom{2n}{n}$$

I started to prove.
We now that $\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})=\sqrt{\pi}$ so the left-hand-side will be:
$$\frac{2\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}+n)}{\Gamma(1+n)}$$
which is equivalent to $2\beta(x,y)$ for $x=\frac{1}{2}$ and $y=n+\frac{1}{2}$
Also $\Gamma(n+1)=n!$ so the right-hand-side is:
$$\frac{\pi}{2^{2n-1}}\frac{(2n)!}{n!\,n!}=\frac{\pi}{2^{2n-1}}\frac{\Gamma(2n+1)}{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(n+1)}$$
But I seem to get no results!

Comment: How do you interpret $\binom{2n}{n}$ for $n < 0$?

Comment: For $n>0$ did you try induction?

Comment: @DanielFischer n>0

Comment: Then change $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ to $n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$ (although there's no reason to exclude $0$). And induction works very well for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that: 
$$ \Gamma(n+1)= n!$$
$$ \Gamma(n+1)=n\Gamma(n)$$ 
$$ \Gamma(2n)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} 2^{2n - 1/2} \; \;  \Gamma(n)  \,\;\Gamma(n+\frac{1}{2})$$
So,if we consider the right hand side (RHS) : 
$$ \frac{\pi}{2^{2n-1}}\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{\pi}{2^{2n-1}} \frac{ (2n)!}{n! \, n! } = \frac{\pi}{2^{2n-1}} \frac{ 2n\Gamma(2n)}{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(n+1)}$$
using the last formula given above and applyinh it  to  $  \Gamma(2n) $: 
$$ RHS=\frac{\pi}{2^{2n-1}} \frac{ 2n}{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(n+1)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} 2^{2n - 1/2} \; \;  \Gamma(n)  \,\;\Gamma(n+\frac{1}{2}) $$
After cancellation

$$ RHS= \frac{2 \sqrt{\pi}  \; \; n } {n \Gamma(n)\Gamma(n+1)}  \Gamma(n)  \,\;\Gamma(n+\frac{1}{2}) = LHS(\text{ Left Hand Side}) $$
Note: The last formula in the above recall is called the  [Duplicate formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General).

Comment: I didn't know about duplicate formula

Comment: @sepideh Thank you for the edit  :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the Gamma function [duplication formula](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.5.E5) for $2n+1$:
$$\Gamma(2n+1)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}2^{2n+1/2}\Gamma(n+\tfrac{1}{2})\Gamma(n+1)$$

Comment: I didn't know about duplicate formula